# Making a dictionary from multiple items in lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to find a way to make a dictionary out of multiple items in lists using a Python script. The lists in question look like this, just to name a few:

```
['331416', 'Macromedaeus', 'distinguendus', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name','|']
['331417', 'Physalopteroidea', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|']
['331418', 'Dracunculus', 'insignis', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|']
['331419', 'Bejaria', 'sprucei', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|']
['331420', 'Paecilomyces', 'sp.', 'JCM', '12545', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|']
```

This is where I'm finding trouble because I'm not sure how to go about doing this. The first item is an ID, the second item an organism genus name, and sometimes there is a species name given as the third item and sometimes there is not, as is the case for the second list. I need to create a dictionary using the ID number as the key and the organism genus and species name (if given) as the value.

How might I go about doing this? I am currently using Python. 2.7.8.

Comment: what have you already tried ?

Comment: Can you give an example output for the given example input?

Comment: `dict((a[0],a[1:]) for a in my_list)` would make a dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input = [
['331416', 'Macromedaeus', 'distinguendus', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name','|'],
['331417', 'Physalopteroidea', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|'],
['331418', 'Dracunculus', 'insignis', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|'],
['331419', 'Bejaria', 'sprucei', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|'],
['331420', 'Paecilomyces', 'sp.', 'JCM', '12545', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|']
]

taxonomy = {}
for r in input:
  taxonomy[r[0]] = {}
  taxonomy[r[0]]['genus'] = r[1]
  if r[2] != '|':
    taxonomy[r[0]]['specie'] = " ".join(r[2:r.index("|")])
```

get following output in `taxonomy`

```
{
'331418': {'genus': 'Dracunculus', 'specie': 'insignis'}, 
'331419': {'genus': 'Bejaria', 'specie': 'sprucei'}, 
'331420': {'genus': 'Paecilomyces', 'specie': 'sp. JCM 12545'}, 
'331416': {'genus': 'Macromedaeus', 'specie': 'distinguendus'}, 
'331417': {'genus': 'Physalopteroidea'}
}
```

Comment: @Russ I fixed a bug in mi old post ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you want a dictionary with keys to be ID#s and values to be a simple list (instead of a dictionary) use a defaultdict, which allows you to have list values.

```
import re # import regular expressions
from collections import defaultdict # use default dictionary


# your lists
combinedlist = [
['331416', 'Macromedaeus', 'distinguendus', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name','|'],
['331417', 'Physalopteroidea', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|'],
['331418', 'Dracunculus', 'insignis', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|'],
['331419', 'Bejaria', 'sprucei', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|'],
['331420', 'Paecilomyces', 'sp.', 'JCM', '12545', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|']
]

# make a regular expression pattern for an id number that is exactly 6 digits
# this is flexible-- if you wanted an id number between 4 and 6 digits, use \d{4,6}
id_num = re.compile("\d{6}")

# your default dictionary which has lists as values
d = defaultdict(list)

# iterate through your combined list
for list in combinedlist:
    n = len(list)
    new_entry = []
    # for all the entries of each list
    for i in range(1, n):
        new_entry.append(list[i])
    d[list[0]] = new_entry


# print 
for key in d.keys():
    print 'key: ',key, '\n    value:',d[key]
```

here's output

```
key:  331418 
    value: ['Dracunculus', 'insignis', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|']
key:  331419 
    value: ['Bejaria', 'sprucei', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|']
key:  331420 
    value: ['Paecilomyces', 'sp.', 'JCM', '12545', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|']
key:  331416 
    value: ['Macromedaeus', 'distinguendus', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|']
key:  331417 
    value: ['Physalopteroidea', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name', '|']
```

Comment: viewing the response from @Jose Ricardo Bustos M. , I've slightly edited my response to make it cleaner (thanks Jose)

Comment: i am very pleased :) .... to practice your algorithm can be simplified to a single line using list comprehension ..... `d = dict([(v[0], v) for v in combinedlist])`

Answer (score -1):

Given one of the lists do something like:

```
mydict = {}
mylist = ['331416', 'Macromedaeus', 'distinguendus', '|', '|', 'scientific', 'name','|']
mydict[mylist[0]] = mylist[1:]

print mydict
```

That takes the ID as the key and makes the rest of the list the value.

Then depending on where these lists are stored, you can loop through and add all of them to the dictionary.